# Passing reclassification values to the Reclassify tool in Model Builder in ArcGIS 10

Tags: arcgis-10.0, geoprocessing, modelbuilder

There is a set of point features that fall within polygon features, and I want these polygon features (after converting them to raster) reclassified based on how many point features fall in them. If the reclassification method, the number of classes, and the new values remain constant, is there any way of passing these to the Reclassify tool every time I run the model?

Answer (score 2):

You can save and load Info Tables.

[image]